# Laravel View Component support on view namespace

Tags: laravel, components, laravel-blade, laravel-7

By default you can add components to resources/views/components and use them using `x-` prefix with blade files.
 I registerd a view namespace which is located on different directory and i want the components directory in that namespace to be discovered as well.

Is there a way on laravel 7 to add additional directory to discover?